# Calcular total por item con Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy empezando con Javascript, y he estado intentando realizar lo siguiente, tengo una tabla con item en el cual por medio de inputs intento calcular el total de cada item, independientemente de la cantidad de items que existan, sin embargo, unicamente solo logro calcular el primer item, de que forma puedo hacer qu me calcule cada item, independientemente de la cantidad de item que halla, agradezco inmensamente su ayuda, comparto mi codigo:

codigo.html

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Cantidad</td>
      <td>Precio</td>
      <td>Subtotal</td>
    </tr>    
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Manzana</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="quantity" onChange="multiplicar();"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="price" onChange="multiplicar();"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="subtotal"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pera</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="quantity" onChange="multiplicar();"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="price" onChange="multiplicar();"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="subtotal"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Uva</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="quantity" onChange="multiplicar();"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="price" onChange="multiplicar();"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="subtotal"></td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="text-right">Total</td>
    </tr>    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

codigo.js

```
<script>

function multiplicar(){
      input1 = document.querySelector(".quantity").value;
      input2 = document.querySelector(".price").value;
      total = parseInt(input1)*parseInt(input2);
      document.querySelector(".subtotal").value = total;
}

</script>
```

#

Actualizacion:

```
function multiplicar(){
    var quantity = document.querySelectorAll('.quantity');
    var price = document.querySelectorAll('.price');

    for(var i = 0; i < quantity.lenght; i++){ 
      console.log(quantity[i].value);
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < price.lenght; i++){ 
      console.log(price[i].value);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí está el código que puedes utilizar:

```
function multiplicar (){
    var quantity = document.querySelectorAll('.quantity');
    var price = document.querySelectorAll('.price');
    var subtotals = document.querySelectorAll('.subtotal');

    for(var i = 0; i < quantity.length; i++){ 
      subtotals[i].value = quantity[i].value * price[i].value;
    }

  }
```

Estabas utilizando lenght en lugar de length, un error de escritura.
Lo que hará el bucle será hacer el calculo de todos los input que tengan la clase quantity y price y la colocará en la posición que le corresponde de subtotal.
Como cada los tres elementos tienen el mismo número de campos, solo necesitamos un bucle.

Comment: Te agradezco Rodrigo va fenomenal! =D

Answer (score 0):

el problema esta en el querySelector. Tu debes utilizar querySelectorAll ya que te referieres a varios items de la clase "quantity" y "price".
querySelectorAll se deve recorrer como un arreglo.

Comment: Acabo de intentar cambiando los querySelector a querySelectorAll y hoy no me calculo ninguno Doormut jeje

Comment: Pero lo estas recorriendo como un array?

Comment: No Doormut eso como seria eso?

Comment: Claro Doormut, me ayudara a enteder mejor =D

Comment: Te dejo un ejemplo: var x = document.querySelectorAll(".clase"); console.log(x[0].value); //muestra el valor del primer elemento console.log(x[1].value); //muestra el valor del segundo elemento

Comment: Excelente Doormut, de que forma puedo mostrar el array? y no solo un valor especifico?

Comment: Podes recorrerlo con un for o un while:  for(var i = 0; i<x.lenght; i++){  console.log(x[¡].value)} //imprimis todos los valores por consola

Comment: Excelente Doormut, voy entendiendo la idea

Comment: No se si te estoy tomando la idea, pero creo que es declarar tanto el campo de cantidad como de precio cada una por medio de un querySelectorAll('price'); y luego iterarla por medio de un for para que recorra cada campo, voy bien?

Comment: Sisi, es eso! Vas bien

Comment: Doormut, acabo de pegar como llevo la idea pero no estoy seguro si voy bien, actualiza el post y lo veras, esta al final del codigo